# Please help me understand mounting cifs for domain group

Tags: samba, network-share, mount, fedora, cifs

I have samba ad dc and on a different member I have a file server.

```
Domain Controller = Debian 11 (DC01)
Domain Member (File Server) = Fedora 34 (FS01)
Domain Member (Workstation) = Fedora 34 (F01)
```

Here are the mount points (F01)

```
/multimedia/Photos
/multimedia/Movies
/multimedia/Music
/multimedia/Videos
```

smb.conf (FS01)

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    dedicated keytab file = /etc/krb5.keytab
    kerberos method = secrets and keytab
    realm = HOME.TEST-SERVER.LAN
    security = ADS
    template homedir = /home/HOME/%U
    template shell = /bin/bash
    username map = /etc/samba/user.map
    winbind refresh tickets = Yes
    winbind use default domain = Yes
    workgroup = HOME
    idmap config * : range = 10000-24999999
    idmap config * : backend = autorid
    map acl inherit = Yes
    vfs objects = acl_xattr


[homes]
    browseable = No
    comment = Home Directories
    read only = No
    valid users = %S


[printers]
    browseable = No
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = Yes


[Photos]
    comment = Photos
    inherit acls = Yes
    path = /multimedia/Photos
    read list = "@HOME\Domain Users"
    read only = No
    valid users = "@HOME\Media Admins" @HOME\Photographers
    write list = @HOME\Photographers


[Videos]
    comment = Videos
    inherit acls = Yes
    path = /multimedia/Videos
    read only = No
    valid users = "@HOME\Video Users"


[Movies]
    comment = Videos
    inherit acls = Yes
    path = /multimedia/Movies
    read only = No
    valid users = "@HOME\Domain Users"


[Music]
    comment = Videos
    inherit acls = Yes
    path = /multimedia/Music
    read only = No
    valid users = "@HOME\Domain Users"


[seagate]
    comment = Videos
    inherit acls = Yes
    path = /media/seagate
    read only = No
    valid users = "@HOME\Domain Users"


[Backup]
    comment = Backup
    inherit acls = Yes
    path = /media/Seagate_1
    read only = No
    valid users = "@HOME\Domain Users"
```

> gio mount smb://fs01/photos (F01)

```
gio: smb://fs01/photos/: Failed to mount Windows share: Permission denied
```

> tail /var/log/messages (F01)

```
Nov  9 15:29:33 FS01 smbd[799696]: [2021/11/09 15:29:33.316583,  0] ../../source3/smbd/service.c:167(chdir_current_service)
Nov  9 15:29:33 FS01 smbd[799696]:  chdir_current_service: vfs_ChDir(/multimedia/Photos) failed: Permission denied. Current token: uid=211104, gid=210513, 8 groups: 211104 210513 211112 211113 109999 109990 109982 10001
```

Above worked at one time but no longer working

> sudo mount -vvv -t cifs //fs01/photos /multimedia/Photos/ -o credentials=/root/.smb (F01)

```
domain=FS01
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.0.0.10,unc=\\fs01\photos,user=redhat,domain=FS01,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

> dmesg (F01)

```
[ 7092.213424] CIFS: Attempting to mount \\fs01\photos
[ 7092.222559] CIFS: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[ 7092.222564] CIFS: VFS: \\fs01 Send error in SessSetup = -13
[ 7092.222571] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

How do I mount these so that access is controlled by Samba where I would just need to update the smb.conf with groups to control access?